# The code does not compile with python 3, but runs fine with python 2

Tags: python

I can run this code with python 2.7, but it does not compile with python 3:

```
lbl = data.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(values)
result = lbl.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(data.count())
```

The error message is:

```
    result = lbl.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(data.count())
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how to make it working with python 3?

Comment: You can no longer [unpack tuples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) in `lambda`s in Py3 (which I think is very unfortunate). You will need `lambda x: x[0] != x[1]` instead of trying to unpack. Fortunately, this works in both Py2 and Py3.

Comment: @AChampion: Great, thanks! I was searching for the solution that works both with python 2 and 3.